# Stack Exchange switches to CommonMark. Computational Science SE: 2020-06-17

Tags: discussion, markdown

At the beginning of June 2020, Stack Exchange [decided to switch the markdown rendered to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/383809). The developers' team wrote migration scripts so that the rendering of the existing posts should remain visually the same and no issues should occur. Several other communities already had their sites converted to CommonMark before us including [Physics SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12936/152812), [TeX SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8583/107975), and Chemistry SE that use "advanced" features, such as MathJax.

While the old posts after the migration should render the same, there are some minor changes to markdown syntaxis: lists, blockquotes, headlines, and code highlighting.

More information about the migration technical details [is available on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/383809), and here is the link for the [migration schedule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348750/383809). **Computational Science SE is scheduled for 2020-06-17**.

It seems that the process is going smoothly. However, in case you notice any problems with the old posts that were caused by migration:

- Ideally, [fix the problem yourself](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12936/physics-is-switching-to-commonmark-on-june-4#comment49158_12937) if you can.

**OR**

- Flag for moderator attention
- Report the bug on [Computational Science Meta](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/) or, if you think it is applicable generally, [on general Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

While this upgrade to CommonMark does not necessarily introduce any new features right away, it certainly should help the developers' life in the long run and can make available say, [markdown table support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/383809), in the nearby future.